# List of ports used for encryption

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, port

I'm developing an app which captures packets and tells if the packet is encrypted. Do you have any idea to how find out if a packet is encrypted? I think there is no header telling us about encryption so i think maybe i should check the ports since some ports are used for some encryption protocols like TLS https or.... Which RFC should i check? I checked rfc1700 for well-known ports, but i think some ports are not listed and some encryption ports are not described as "used for encryption protocols or sth like it" . so I'm stuck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately questions like these are [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please try to reduce the scope of your question, and ask [minimal specific programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: TLS doesn't have a standard port.  I can execute a TLS connection on port 80 if I want to.  How will you tell?

Answer (score 1):

There are well known ports for some encrypted protocols like https, however aside from data that is sent to/from publicly known encrypted ports & protocols, there is no way to know if any particular packets contain encrypted data or not.

For example, a packet that contains the bytes ". . . 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10 . . ." might be encrypted data or it might be part of a picture of a puppy. There's no way to know without knowing what the entire data stream is supposed to look like; then reassembling it and checking it against data and patterns that you *can* identify.

With unlimited resources, you could actually check the data stream against all known data types. This would let you say "That's an image file and it's a puppy" or "That's not an image file" but you still couldn't be sure if it's encrypted, random or just some other non-encrypted thing you *don't* know about.

Just to muddy the water further, any protocol can be sent over any port. The port numbers are just a convention. For example, there are apps that tunnel data using the DNS port.

Even more confusing is it actually could be a [legitimate picture of a puppy, with data encoded into the image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).